# Problemas ao criar API com banco Firebird e Node JS

Tags: node.js, api, firebird

Estou estudando como desenvolver uma API para consultar dados de um banco firebird. Para fazer isso estou usando o node-firebird, mas a conexão não parece estar funcionando.

Segue trecho do código:

```html
const firebird = require('node-firebird');

var options = {};
 
options.host = '127.0.0.1';
options.port = 3050;
options.database = 'C:/PASTA/DADOS/BANCO.FDB';
options.user = 'SYSDBA';
options.password = 'masterkey';
options.lowercase_keys = false; // set to true to lowercase keys
options.role = null;            // default
options.pageSize = 4096;

const consulta = firebird.attach(options, (err, db) => {
    
    if (err){
       //throw err;
    }
    else{
        db.query('SELECT * FROM UCTABUSERS', function(err,result){
            try{
                console.log('A função funcionou');
                this.usuarios = result;
                db.detach();
            }catch{
                throw err;
            }
        });
    }

    return this.usuarios;
});

module.exports = consulta;
```

Eu utilizo essa função em outro arquivo javascript. O problema é que não apresenta mensagem ou erro, apenas o retorno que está vazio.

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Resolvi esse problema utilizando outro método dessa biblioteca. Utilizei o metodo pool para abrir a conexão e fazer a consulta. Segue o trecho do código:

Comment: const rows = async () => {
  try{
      
    try{
        var pool = client.pool(5, options);

        pool.get(function(err, db) {

            try{
                db.query("SELECT * FROM UCTABUSERS where UCIDUSER = 1", function(err, result) {
                setResultado(result);
                db.detach();
                });
            }catch{
                console.log(err);
                return err;
            }
        });

        pool.destroy();

Comment: console.log('Retorno : '+ getResultado());
        return getResultado();

    }catch{
        return 'Não foi possivel abrir a conexão';
    }
    }catch{
        return "Não foi possivel conectar ao banco de dados";
    }
};

Comment: Gustavo poderia postar o codigo completo corrigido, pois tenho o mesmo problema,
e como sou novo com node.js não consegui entender aonde trocar o código.

Answer (score -1):

O código que usei para conseguir fazer funcionar foi esse ai.

```html
const express = require("express");

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/listagem", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const client = require("../database/index");

    var options = require("../database/config");

    var pool = client.pool(5, options);

    pool.get(function(err, db) {
      try {
        db.query(
          "SELECT cast(CPF as varchar(18) character set win1252) as CGC_CPF, cast(cliente as varchar(45) character set win1252) as cliente FROM CLIENTE",
          function(err, result) {
            try {
              if (err) {
                return res
                  .status(400)
                  .send({
                    error:
                      "Ocorreu um erro ao tentar fazer a consulta de Clientes. Erro : " +
                      err
                  });
              }

              if (result != undefined) {
                return res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
              } else {
                res
                  .status(400)
                  .send({ error: "Não existem dados para ser retornados" });
              }
            } catch {
              res.status(400).send({ error: "Falha ao buscar dados no banco" });
            }
          }
        );
        db.detach();
      } catch {
        console.log("Ocorreu um erro ao gerar o pool conexões");
      }
    });
  } catch {
    res
      .status(400)
      .send({ error: "Falha ao carregar os dados de clientes do servidor" });
  }
});

module.exports = app => app.use("/clientes", router);
```